# mySQL different ORDER BY based on different WHERE

Tags: mysql

I could run the each query separately and then output the data immediately following each other but I am hoping there is a way to do it in one query.

I am looking for all the records to be displayed but have all records with `col_1=""` at the top and sorted accordingly and then below that have all records with `col_1!=""` sorted accordingly (different than the fist `order by`)

I am hope I explained it ok.

Here are 2 sample queries that I would like handled as I described.

```
Select * from table where col_1 ="" order by col_5,col_4,col_3;
Select * from table where col_1!="" order by col_3,col_4,col_5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from your_table 
order by col_1 <> '',
         case when col_1 = '' then col_3 else col_5 end,
         col_4,
         case when col_1 = '' then col_5 else col_3 end
```

Comment: `col_3` and `col_5` should have the same datatype or implicit conversion has to be possible. Example col3 is INT and col5 is DATETIME will fail.

Comment: Note that rows where `col_1` is NULL would be included. You would have to exclude them in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way I tackle things like this is a variation of the method Juergen's answer suggests, but handles type differences:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table AS t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col_1 = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
   , CASE WHEN col_1 = '' THEN col_5 ELSE /* valid literal value for type of col_5 */ END
   , CASE WHEN col_1 <> '' THEN col_3 ELSE /* /* valid literal value for type of col_3 */ */ END
   , col_4
   , CASE WHEN col_1 = '' THEN col_3 ELSE /* valid literal value for type of col_3 */ END
   , CASE WHEN col_1 <> '' THEN col_5 ELSE /* valid literal value for type of col_5 */ END
```

When the fields are compatible data types, Juergen's answer may perform slightly better (having less overall sort dimensions).